# Scheme list of strings

Tags: string, list, scheme

my function in scheme looks like this

```
(define (func1 input)
  (let kloop ((x 6))
    (let ((act (string-copy (func2 input2))))
      (if (eq? act "") (display "null") (display act))
      (if (> x 0) (kloop (- x 1)))))))
```

func2 return some string which is stored in act. Now I have to create a list of all strings returned by this function. Here above, I am just displaying those strings. I tried different approaches, but nothing is working out. I tried using append and cons.

Please suggest.

Comment: What is `input2`?  Why `string-copy` (something is destructively modifying the result of `func2`)?

Comment: And, of course, displaying something is not the same as returning something.  Displaying produces a printed representation of the object; returning returns the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last `if` is missing the else case, which is where one would expect the return value of the function to be.

You don't mention how you've tried to use `append` and `cons`, but a common pattern is to pass an accumulating parameter around in the loop:

```
(define (five input)
  (let loop ((x 5) (outputs '()))
    (if (> x 0) 
        (loop (- x 1) (cons input outputs))
        outputs)))

> (five "yes")
'("yes" "yes" "yes" "yes" "yes")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `func2` on `input` six times.  Does it return a different value each time?  If not, this works:

```
(define (func1 input)
  (make-list 6 (func2 input)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit confusing, you should provide a sample of the expected output for a given input. And why the empty string is treated differently in your code? apparently the recursion should advance on the value of `x`, not the value of the string returned by `func2`. Also, why are you copying the string? seems unnecessary.

Assuming that the named `let` is used just for keeping track of the number of iterations, this solution seems aligned with your intent, as this will return a 6-element list of all strings returned by `func2`

```
(define (func1 input)
  (let kloop ((x 6))
    (if (zero? x)
        '()
        (cons (func2 input)
              (kloop (- x 1))))))
```

But we can be smarter and use the named `let` to give a [tail-recursive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) solution, which is more efficient:

```
(define (func1 input)
  (let kloop ((x 6)
              (acc '()))
    (if (zero? x)
        acc
        (kloop (- x 1)
               (cons (func2 input)
                     acc)))))
```

Comment: Prefer return in your tail recursive version to be `(reverse acc)` (to be consistent with your non-tail recursive solution).

Comment: @GoZoner yes and no :P it depends on the answer to your question: if `func2` always returns the same value, then there's no need to reverse at the end. If it _does_ return different values, I agree with you, a `reverse` must be performed at the end of the tail-recursive version of the procedure